# Give regular user permission to access physical drive on Windows

Tags: windows, permissions, uac

Is there a way to assign permissions to a regular user to access a physical device/drive on Windows?

The idea is to bypass "error: Cannot open the raw disk '\.\PhysicalDrive1'. Otherwise, it looks like I might have to disable UAC and run everything as an Administrator, which isn't ideal!

Answer (score 3):

In short you can't easily. Here's why:

Using PowerShell we can get the ACLs for a physical "raw" disk drive:

```
PS C:\> [io.directory]::GetAccessControl("\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1") | Format-List


Path   :
Owner  : BUILTIN\Administrators
Group  : NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
Access : Everyone Allow  ExecuteFile, ReadAttributes, ReadPermissions, Synchronize
         NT AUTHORITY\RESTRICTED Allow  ExecuteFile, ReadAttributes, ReadPermissions, Synchronize
         NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM Allow  FullControl
         BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl
Audit  :
Sddl   : O:BAG:SYD:(A;;FX;;;WD)(A;;FX;;;RC)(A;;FA;;;SY)(A;;FA;;;BA)
```

So only `SYSTEM` and `Administrators` have permissions that allow write access to the drive defeating your initial request.

There seem to be third party tools (such as [User-mode Raw Disk Access](http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dskacl/)) that work around this but it doesn't seem to be something that Microsoft were intending to support on fixed (non-removable) disks. See [Changes to the file system and to the storage stack to restrict direct disk access and direct volume access in Windows Vista and in Windows Server 2008](https://web.archive.org/web/20160319034046/https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/942448) (archive.org link because original article has been removed) for Microsoft's take.